# Why is the sqlite query not working if the search is for with a larger string?

Tags: python, sqlite, full-text-search

```
c.execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS text_idx  USING fts4 (id, title, book, author, date, chapter, verse, passage, link, documentType, tokenize={});".format("oulatin"))
    c.execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS text_idx_porter  USING fts4 (id, title, book, author, date, chapter, verse, passage, link, documentType, tokenize={});".format("porter"))
    c.execute("commit;")
    print("virtual table created")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO text_idx (id, title, book, author, date, chapter, verse, passage, link, documentType) SELECT id, title, book, author, date, chapter, verse, passage, link, documentType FROM texts;")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO text_idx_porter (id, title, book, author, date, chapter, verse, passage, link, documentType) SELECT id, title, book, author, date, chapter, verse, passage, link, documentType FROM texts;")
    print ("inserted data into virtual table")
    stmt1="select id, title, book, author, link from text_idx where passage MATCH 'EPITHALAMIUM DE NUPTIIS HONORII'"
    stmt2="select id, title, book, author, link from text_idx_porter where passage MATCH 'EPITHALAMIUM DE NUPTIIS HONORII'"
    r1=c.execute(stmt1)
    r2=c.execute(stmt2)
    r3=(set(r1.fetchall()) or set(r2.fetchall()))
    r4=list(r3)
    print (r4)
```

this code when executed gives the following query result:
[]

However, it gives out a result for a condition that is a single word.

why is this?

Comment: Are you sure your `MATCH` query would work for multiple words (separated by spaces)?

Comment: Also, you don't `commit` the inserts at any point.

Comment: @roganjosh Commits are not needed to see changes made by the same connection.

Comment: You are not searching for a larger string but for four tokens. Anyway, is `c` a connection or a cursor?

Comment: c is the cursor. so how do i search for four tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in the code. I registered both the tokenizers with the same code. porter is default so no need to register it.